# Stubhub API Url For Inventory Listings

Tags: python, api

I am trying to access Stubhubs listings in their inventory for a given event through their API subscriptions but for some reason keep getting a return of page not found.

Their API subscription page claims this is their listing URL:

https://api.stubhub.com/inventory/listings/v1/[insert event code]

For exmaple:
    https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v1/9441783

This use to return all listings for the event but now does not work.
So I am wondering if anyone knows the new URL possibly a v2? or if it appears the API has turned off?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also had an issue with this, and no option for registering for v2 through the developer portal.

I wrote an email to apisupport@stubhub.com, and they informed me that v1 was deprecated. They gave me access to v2, so I would suggest that you write to them and state your account email address and application name you need access for.

Comment: Thanks ay-uk.... I got access to v2 and scraping but it looks like the source is only 100 listings. Did you manage to get the total listings for a given event?

Comment: Just add the following parameters (max 1000 listings in this example): limit=1000&start=0&rows=1000